# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent toArray sets attribute to 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a payment object which looks like this when reading it from the database and calling **dd($payment)**

```
#attributes: array:7 [▼
"user_id" => 90
"plan_id" => 4
"payment_id" => "AP-4AF14082B16992740"
"status" => "done"
"progress" => 0
"created_at" => "2016-05-04 18:05:48"
"updated_at" => "2016-05-04 18:06:21"
]
```

However when calling toArray() on it - it looks like this

```
array:7 [▼
  "user_id" => 90
  "plan_id" => 4
  "payment_id" => 0
  "status" => "done"
  "progress" => 0
  "created_at" => "2016-05-04 18:05:48"
"updated_at" => "2016-05-04 18:06:21"
]
```

Any ideas why?

Query:

```
$payment = Auth::user()->payments()->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: Can we see the code that performs the query to create this `$payment` variable?

Comment: are you able to access $payment['user_id'] after using toArray()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because one of three possibilities, (both in the `Payment` model):

#### 1

There is an Accessor set looking like:

```
public function getPaymentIdAttribute($value) {
    return (int)$value;
}
```

#### 2

You have set `$casts` field in the model that looks like:

```
protected $casts = [
    ...
    'payment_id' => 'integer',
    ...
];
```

---

If you're calling the `$attributes` array, these two things won't lunch.

**EDIT**

#### 3

This one is your answer:

Because if the `payment_id` is a primary key in model - then laravel model's automatically cast it to int on `toArray()` call. The solution for that is to cast it (it will overrides Laravel defaults) as a string like this, in the `Payment` model:

```
protected $casts = [
    ...
    'payment_id' => 'string',
    ...
];
```

Comment: payment id is set as primary key in the model

Comment: ok... that's the third option probably :) I will check and write here in the moment...

Comment: Yep! When field is a key (is incrementing) Laravel model's casting it automatically to int - and that's way you get 0 there. In this case - you can recast it <- I've reedit my entry

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working